# In Django 3/Python, what is the preferred way to remove orphaned records?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, foreign-keys, orphaned-objects

I'm using Django 3 and Python 3.8.  I have the following model ...

```
class Coop(models.Model):
    objects = CoopManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    types = models.ManyToManyField(CoopType, blank=False)
    addresses = models.ManyToManyField(Address)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    phone = models.ForeignKey(ContactMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='contact_phone')
    email = models.ForeignKey(ContactMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='contact_email')
    web_site = models.TextField()
```

Note the "phone" and "email" foreign key columns.  Is there any Django/Python specific way to automatically remove the ContactMethod records once they become orphaned?  That is, if I have my model, in which both columns are populated, and then run

```
coop.phone = None
coop.save(update_fields=['phone'])
```

Is there anything that will automatically delete the orphaned records?  Or I guess what is the standard way to achieve this?  I'm running a MySql 8 db, but i would prefer to exclude DB-specific solutions.

Comment: You can try to use signals, but that will not work for `.update(..)`s, `.delete(..)`, etc. in the ORM. It might be better to regularly run a management command that cleans up the non-referenced `ContactMethod`s.

Comment: No, there isn't. But, you can create a *Django management command* and can run it periodically

Answer (score 1):

You can define a Django signal, but Django signals do not always run. Especially when you make ORM calls that perform *bulk* updates or *bulk* removals. For example if you set the `email` and/or `phone` of all `Coop`s with `enabled=False` with `Coop.objects.filter(enabled=False).update(email=None, phone=None)`, then it will not run `post_save` signals, and thus some `ContactMethod`s can be orphaned without the signal being triggered.

Even if you could use a signal, it might not be a good idea. One can also make updates to the database without the ORM query, for example the database administrator through the *PhpMyAdmin* frontend. So even if it was possible in Django, it would mean one can still orphan objects through another way. Furthermore such signal would handle one `ContactMethod` at the time, which is more expensive than deleting `ContactMethod`s in *bulk*.

You can make a [*management command* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/#module-django.core.management) that you can run periodically, for example once a day. You can define such management command in your *`app`*:

```
app/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    management/
        __init__.py
        commands/
            __init__.py
            remove_orphan_contactmethod.py
    urls.py
    views.py
```

In the `app/management/commands/remove_orphan_contactmethod.py`, you can then detect and remove these `ContactMethod` objects:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from app.models import ContactMethod

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Remove ContactMethods not referenced through email or phone'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        items = ContactMethod.objects.filter(
            contact_phone=None, contact_email=None
        ).delete()
        number = items.get('app.ContactMethod', 0)
        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS(f'Removed {number} ContactMethod object(s)'))
```

Then you can run:

```
python3 manage.py remove_orphan_contactmethods
```

To run the command. You can for example specify a [*cronjob* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) or some other recurring task mechanism to perform this command at a certain frequency.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use django-cleanup (https://github.com/un1t/django-cleanup), but since I added it after releasing to production, I had to create a Django command to clean up orphan files in the media folder of my S3. As it was challenging to find an existing solution, I'm sharing the command here:

```
import os
import sys

import boto3
from django.apps import apps
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.core.validators import EMPTY_VALUES
from django.db import models


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Manage orphan files in S3"

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument(
            "--list_orphans",
            action="store_true",
            help="List all orphan files in the media folder of the S3     bucket",
        )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--list_bucket_files",
        action="store_true",
        help="List all files in the S3 bucket",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--list_used_files",
        action="store_true",
        help="List all files used by an object in the django application",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--list_fields",
        action="store_true",
        help="Show file fields detected in django application",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--delete",
        action="store_true",
        help="Delete all orphan files in the S3 bucket",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--stats",
        action="store_true",
        help="Show statistics of files in the S3 bucket",
    )

def handle(self, *args, **options):
    custom_args = ["list_orphans", "list_bucket_files", "list_used_files", "list_fields", "delete", "stats"]

    # Check if all custom arguments are False
    if all(options[arg] is False for arg in custom_args):
        print("No custom arguments provided, displaying help text.")
        prog_name = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
        subcommand = self.__class__.__name__.lower()
        self.print_help(prog_name, subcommand)
        return

    s3 = get_s3_client()
    aws_storage_bucket_name = get_bucket_name()

    if options["list_orphans"]:
        used_media = get_used_media()
        all_media = list_s3_objects(s3, aws_storage_bucket_name)
        orphan_files = all_media - used_media
        self.stdout.write(f"Number of orphan files: {len(orphan_files)}")
        if orphan_files:
            self.stdout.write("Orphan files:")
            for orphan_file in orphan_files:
                self.stdout.write(f"- {orphan_file}")

    if options["list_bucket_files"]:
        all_media = list_s3_objects(s3, aws_storage_bucket_name)
        self.stdout.write(f"Total files in bucket: {len(all_media)}")
        self.stdout.write("Files in bucket:")
        for file in all_media:
            self.stdout.write(f"- {file}")

    if options["list_used_files"]:
        used_media = get_used_media()
        self.stdout.write(f"Total used files: {len(used_media)}")
        self.stdout.write("Used files:")
        for used_file in used_media:
            self.stdout.write(f"- {used_file}")

    if options["list_fields"]:
        file_fields = get_file_fields()
        self.stdout.write("File fields detected in django application:")
        for field in file_fields:
            self.stdout.write(f"- {field}")

    if options["delete"]:
        used_media = get_used_media()
        all_media = list_s3_objects(s3, aws_storage_bucket_name)
        orphan_files = all_media - used_media
        if orphan_files:
            self.stdout.write(f"Found {len(orphan_files)} orphan files.")
            user_input = input("Do you want to delete these orphan files? (yes/no): ").strip().lower()
            if user_input == "yes":
                self.stdout.write(f"Deleting {len(orphan_files)} orphan files...")
                deleted_files_count = delete_orphan_files(s3, aws_storage_bucket_name, orphan_files)
                self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS(f"Total files deleted: {deleted_files_count}"))
            else:
                self.stdout.write(self.style.WARNING("File deletion aborted by the user."))
        else:
            self.stdout.write("No orphan files detected")

    if options["stats"]:
        self.stdout.write(f"Total files in bucket: {len(all_media)}")
        self.stdout.write(f"Total used files: {len(used_media)}")
        self.stdout.write(f"Total orphan files: {len(orphan_files)}")


def get_s3_client():
    aws_access_key_id = os.getenv("DJANGO_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
    aws_secret_access_key = os.getenv("DJANGO_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")

    if not aws_access_key_id:
        raise CommandError("DJANGO_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID environment variable not set")
    elif not aws_secret_access_key:
        raise CommandError("DJANGO_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment variable not set")

    if settings.SETTINGS_MODULE == "config.settings.local":
        s3 = boto3.client(
            service_name="s3",
            aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
            aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
            endpoint_url="http://minio:9000",
        )
    else:
       s3 = boto3.client(
            service_name="s3",
            aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
            aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
        )

    return s3


def get_bucket_name():
   aws_storage_bucket_name = os.getenv("DJANGO_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME")
    if not aws_storage_bucket_name:
       raise CommandError("DJANGO_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME environment variable not set")
   return aws_storage_bucket_name


def get_file_fields():
    all_models = apps.get_models()
    fields = []

    for model in all_models:
        for field in model._meta.get_fields():
            if isinstance(field, models.FileField) or isinstance(field, models.ImageField):
                fields.append(field)

    return fields


def get_used_media():
    """
    Get media which are still used in models
    """
    media = set()

    for field in get_file_fields():
        is_null = {f"{field.name}__isnull": True}
        is_empty = {f"{field.name}": ""}

        for value in (
            field.model._base_manager.values_list(field.name,     flat=True).exclude(**is_empty).exclude(**is_null)
        ):
            if value not in EMPTY_VALUES:
                normalized_value = value if value.startswith("media/") else f"media/{value}"
                media.add(normalized_value)

    return media


def list_s3_objects(s3_client, bucket_name, folder="media/"):
    """
    List all objects in an S3 bucket
   """
    objects = set()
    paginator = s3_client.get_paginator("list_objects_v2")
    for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=folder):
        for obj in page.get("Contents", []):
            objects.add(obj["Key"])
    return objects


def delete_orphan_files(s3_client, bucket_name, orphan_files):
    deleted_count = 0

    for file_key in orphan_files:
        try:
            response = s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_key)
             if response["ResponseMetadata"]["HTTPStatusCode"] == 204:
                 print(f"Successfully deleted: {file_key}")
                 deleted_count += 1
            else:
                 print(f"Failed to delete: {file_key}, Response: {response}")
        except Exception as e:
             print(f"Error deleting {file_key}: {e}")

     return deleted_count
```

I'd appreciate any tips or suggestions to enhance it if you have an